# Visual Studio Community 2019 SSRS report not showing data in table

Tags: visual-studio-2019, ssrs-2019

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 Community edition. I had some trouble getting the Reporting Services extension installed but eventually managed. When I create a report the data in the tablix does not display when being Previewed. See below my report in design mode:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The yellow box has the word SERIOUSLY! in it. This box was not showing the text in it (in Preview mode) until I coloured it yellow. The tablix should show 14 lines of data but is blank when Previewed:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks
Rob
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDqw0.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OtjH.png

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue as you are facing right now.
I had tried a solution and it worked for me.

Select all the columns in the Design page and then go to properties.
Go to Font and then change the font to Arial Narrow.
Then save the report and preview it.

It worked for me.
Please do let me know if this solution worked for you as well or was it a fluke at my end.

Regards
Ankit S